# Javascript Date Picker Into A Textfield

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I'm trying to use a date picker for a date field but my date fields ID is a dynamic id, since the fields generates in table rows, like

```
<input type="text" id="date<%=n%>"/>
```

But my date picker script requires the ID to attach the date picker into the above text field like below,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        new datepickr('datepick', { dateFormat: 'Y-m-d' });
    </script>
```

Is there any other way to make this work?

Comment: Can't u use same dynamic ID used in generated textbox? E.g. `new datepickr('date<%=n%>', { dateFormat: 'Y-m-d' });` ?

Comment: You can use any kind of jQuery selector to find this particular `input`. Class, expressions, etc.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Just tried it but ddnt work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use one class instead of multiple id's .you can differentiate the text filed value based on index number of class

```
first:<input type="text" class="date">
second:<input type="text" class="date">
third:<input type="text" class="date">

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.date').datepicker(); 
    $('.date').on('change',function(){
       var index=$('.date') .index(this);
       $('.date:eq('+index+')').val();        
    });
});
```

js fiddle link:  http://jsfiddle.net/sarath704/LhPP2/1/

Answer (score 3):

Add a class to your input field

```
<input type="text" id="date<%=n%>" class="datepicker"/>
```

and get its value from javascript

```
var date = $('.datepicker').datepicker();
```